# Unable to access an SQL Server database created via Plesk in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, plesk, ssms-2014

In Plesk v12.5.30, I have created a new SQL Server database named `ngo_database` and a new database user called `ngo_databaseuser`.

I can connect to this new database via Navicat for SQL Server v12.1.20 (after providing host “xxx” + user name “ngo_databaseuser” + password + initial database “ngo_database”), And I am able to access “ngo_database” database and create new tables and queries.

But when I try to connect via SSMS 2014 (after providing server name “xxx” + login “ngo_databaseuser” + password + connect to database “ngo_database”), I am not able to access “ngo_database” database and the only databases available are master + tempdb. And I am not able to import nor create a new user database.

BTW, I have checked with the hosting company and the “Grant the ALTER DATABASE permission to all Microsoft SQL Server database users” is checked.

What I am doing wrong and why I can’t access the database via SSMS?

Comment: The database was created via Plesk, and it allowed only to create a new database user which i named as "ngo_databaseuser".
I was able to access the database "ngo_database" via Navicat, but i was not able to do so via SSMS

Comment: I don't want any more permissions, I only need to access the "ngo_database" via SSMS since I can already access it via Navicat

Comment: What error do you get when trying to access the database in SSMS?

Comment: I get no error upon accessing the database in SSMS. It just that i get access to master and tempdb system databases but I got no access to "ngo_database" user database. I can't even see it in object explorer in SSMS.

Comment: If you don't get an error, how do you know you don't have access..? Not seeing the data ase in the object explorer doesn't mean you don't have access, it means you don't have the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission, either due to it being revoked from `public` or it being denied on your user or a role you have. Try actually writing a query against the database; I bet it works. Maybe `SELECT * FROM ngo_database.sys.tables;`. If it doesn't work, post the error.

Comment: I can access the "ngo_database" user database in Navicat but not in SSMS

Comment: So what error do you get when you try to access it..?

Comment: Thanks. After issuing your command it returned the tables that do exist in ngo_database. So why is it that i can not see these tables in object explorer?. It seems I am missing something!!

Comment: I covered that in the comment above too.

Comment: But the tables are visible to me via navicat!!. As I stated in the original post, the MS SQL database was created via Plesk so the permissions things were arranged by Plesk not by myself

Comment: `VIEW ANY DATABASE` is a server level permission, not database. Plesk won't be able to give or take that permission from you unless it has `sysadmin` privileges; and if it does it needs it removed. If you need `VIEW ANY DATABASE` you need to talk to your DBA about it.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am not an expert in SQL Server. Is there a permission where I can only view "ngo_database" database objects in SMSS object explorer. Since requesting VIEW ANY DATABASE from dba might be impractical

Comment: You can still see the objects in the database though, just SSMS won't show them in the object explorer; because when it reads the `sys.databases` object it won't see it, and that's how it populates it. You need to talk to your DBA here.

Comment: You have been a great help, would you please post your answer so that others can benefit and i mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being a see a database in the object explorer of SSMS does not equate to not being able to access it. When you can only see the databases `master` and `tempdb` this very likely means that either you have had a `DENY` permission for `VIEW ANY DATABASE` added to your login, or a Server Role it belongs to, or `VIEW ANY DATABASE` has been revoked from the `public` role and you haven't been granted it.

SSMS builds the list in the object explorer by using the `sys` objects, and without `VIEW ANY DATABASE`, it can't see the databases you have access to to retrieve the relevant objects from it.

You can check if you have access to the database by using `USE {Your Database}` or trying to query a table (such as `SELECT * FROM {Your Database}.sys.objects;`).

If you *need* the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission, you need to speak to your DBA.

Comment: And you can connect directly to your specific database in SSMS by providing the name in Options tab of the connection dialog.